# New York Comic Con 2011 - Gaming.SE involvement

Tags: discussion, community-event

[New York Comic Con](http://www.newyorkcomiccon.com/) is approaching soon (October 13-16) and I would like for this site to have a presence of some sort. Here's what I tentatively propose:

- Up to **20 users** from Gaming.SE can attend with weekend passes, courtesy of Stack Exchange
- all users in attendance will get a Stack Exchange NYCC swag package (which would *possibly* include the Gaming.SE t-shirt, the Gaming.SE business cards, a Stack Exchange tote bag, a Stack Exchange lanyard, etc.) to hopefully use at the con and, also, your day-to-day existence
- all users (possibly only 21+ users) may be invited to a NYCC Stack Exchange party held at a bar near the Javits Center, with free drinks and/or food for a TBD period of time
- users involved with the blog are encouraged to liveblog the event; I will try to get those users press passes

That's what I have in mind. If there's a big gap in my thinking, please fill it with your knowledge! AKA, leave a comment. In the future I could see Stack Exchange having an actual booth presence, but that's cutting it a little close for October. Starting small. But before we discuss the bullet points in detail, I really just want to know:

**Are any of you already going to New York Comic Con/would you go if Stack Exchange bought your ticket?**

If the answer is yes, please e-mail me at **brett [at] stackexchange [dot] com** with the title **NYCC 2011 - Gaming.SE involvement**: :

1. Your name
2. Your address
3. What days you wish to attend
4. If you wish to write content for the blog

Full disclosure, I mostly copied this post from a similar one I just put up in [Sci-Fi & Fantasy](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/725/new-york-comic-con-2011-scifi-fantasy-se-involvement). If you want, go say hi to your SE cousins and see who else is interested in this. Thanks!

Comment: Too bad this wasn't in time for PAX Prime 2011.  But if anyone is going (to PAX) we should arrange a meetup

Comment: I'm going to PAX Prime.

Comment: I live in NYC, was planning on grabbing a day pass for comiccon. So yes, I'd love to rep SE for a weekend.

Comment: I added email information to the post. LessPop and Matthew, please email me your information and I will get your tickets ordered soon. Also, tzenes and KatieK, I'm going to get to work on PAX Prime stuff right now. I don't know what I can offer this close to the show, but I'm going to try to come up with SOMEthing.

Comment: Make sure to atreply us if you want to ensure people see an update :). Heads up @Less

Comment: what is the connection between comic con and videogames? Other than comic book movie to videogame adaptations? I'm unclear..

Comment: Video game companies exhibit all of their games at comic cons, not just comic book related games. For example, Alienware, the custom gaming PC company, usually has the biggest and most elaborate setup of any company on the floor. On top of that, vendors sell new and vintage games as well as merchandise for games. Comic cons are never just "comic" cons anymore; the term "comic con" is a blanket term (albeit inaccurate) used to include comics, film, television, video games, anime, etc.

Comment: Hey Brett, @Jeff PAX East registration just opened today, would there be some kind of event possible similar to comic con for that?

Comment: @yx. I've already emailed PAX East about involvement. We are planning on doing an event!

Comment: that sounds very interesting, I'll be sure to keep an eye out on meta for that post

Comment: @yx. Jeff doesn't work at Stack Exchange anymore, so don't ping him for SE related queries :)

Comment: @badp he was at this time last year :P

Comment: oh whoops........