# Are you going to PAX Prime Aug. 26-28th?

Tags: discussion, conferences

In response to the [NYCC thread](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2615/new-york-comic-con-2011-gaming-se-involvement), I am trying to get something together for the users venturing to Seattle for PAX Prime. With it being under a week away, it's too late for us to offer free tickets to the convention and get show specific merchandise created. What we can do, however, includes the following:

- Provide users that are attending with a printable badge promoting their affiliation with Gaming.SE and attendance at PAX (below; thanks to Jin for whipping this up!)

  [image: PaxGamingSE]
- Possibly plan a lunch meetup on August 27th for those in attendance
- Possibly provide attendees with a limited number of shirts and stickers to wear and distribute at the convention

Those are the ideas that [KatieK](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/users/2262/katiek) and I came up with (thanks Katie!). If you are attending the convention and are interested in any of these ideas or have suggestions, please let me know in the comments! We're limited by time, but we want to make your PAX Prime experience even more awesome.

Comment: Why does the badge get lasers but not our site!?

Comment: @Jin you are a god of pixels! That's so cool! :D

Comment: @grace that's no laser, that's its....

Comment: I'll be at PAX and would love to nerd out with some fellow stackexchangers.

Comment: this makes soooo much more sense than comic-con

Comment: If you're going, you can follow me on Twitter - http://twitter.com/KatieK2.

Answer (score 6):

So, I will be in attendance at PAX Prime this year, same as I have done every year.

You can see my post from last year [on the blog](http://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/2010/09/06/pax-prime-2010/).  I'll be following up with a similar one this year.  Also, for the people coming out, I'll be willing to buy a drink for anyone who can tell me my up-to-the-minute rep score! (one per person).

---

Speaking of drinks.  I plan to be at [Von's](http://www.vonsroasthouse.com/) on Saturday night

Comment: I have a feeling that if someone will start telling you your up-to-date rep score, by the time they finish the sentence it will already be incorrect.

Comment: @tzenes - Von's is an excellent choice!  I will be there for lunch on Saturday (12:30 - 1:30pm), but probably will be busy around dinner time, alas.

Comment: I'm here now. You can find me in a collared shirt with sunglasses on my head

Answer (score 5):

Yes, I am.  And you should try to find me.

**How?**
http://twitter.com/KatieK2

**Why?**

[image: Shirts, stickers]

---

On Saturday for lunch, I will be at [Von's Roasthouse](http://www.vonsroasthouse.com/) from 12:30 - 1:30 pm.  "Ask for Stack Exchange Gaming".  Stay or grab a shirt / stickers and run - it's all good.

Answer (score 2):

<s>I won't be at PAX (couldn't get a badge), but I live in the area and would be willing to participate in a meet-up.</s>

**Edit**: I will be at PAX on Sunday; I was able to borrow a badge for the day.